# Indian regional language pack. Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, locale, language-package

How to get Indian regional language pack for Magento

`e.g Marathi, Hindi, Tamil, Bengali, etc.`

Because there are more than 20K magento developers, all across India, working on both CE and EE.

Comment: PLs check Indian language pack here https://crowdin.com/project/magento-1